# How to query price items for a customer, in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying the following :

```
stripe.Product.list(limit=3)
```

however this is quite generic and I dont find any [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list?lang=python) to limit the query to a certain customer.
I apreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products and Prices are designed to be reusable and aren't restricted to a single user, therefore it doesn't really make sense to list either of them by Customer ID.

If instead you're looking for a specific transaction that is linked to a Customer, you'll want to list either [Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer) or [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list#list_payment_intents-customer) by Customer ID.